# How to enable users to scroll through a modal on a mobile device?

Tags: html, css, vue.js, responsive-design

I have a modal component asking users to input their username and password, however, when I attempt to input either the username or password, I virtual keyboard pops up blocking the view of what I'm typing. See the image below. I'd like to be able to scroll down to see the input field, but I cannot do that. I'm not entirely sure where I should add the relevant CSS to fix this, but the CSS for my modal is defined in [this file](https://github.com/ivan-rivera/sleep_rescue_client/blob/master/components/layout/Modal.vue#L40) and it looks like this:

```
.sr-modal {
  @apply fixed top-5 left-6 right-6 overflow-y-scroll overflow-x-hidden
  focus:outline-none
  ml-auto mr-auto pt-10 pb-5
  text-dark
  border-2 border-white
  bg-dark
  shadow-lg
  rounded-2xl
  z-30;
  max-width: 25rem;
}
```

Note that I'm using TailwindCSS but it shouldn't really matter. Also, note that my modal is a Vue component (also shouldn't matter).

If anyone has any suggestions, please let me know!

[image]

Comment: this can be achieved in either ways (i) making the form smaller (ii) shifting the whole form to extereme top.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I don't think this is a good solution because I have other modals which require more information, so even if I shift them all the way to the top, it's not going to be enough to see the input fields. I could potentially make the page taller, but I thought that there should be a better solution

Comment: if none of the stuff works then this can be done with multiple data entry pages.

Comment: Surely this can be done with a modal :)

Comment: One more thing: even if my page was taller, I still can't seem to scroll through the modal itself, even when the modal is open, I can scroll through the background page only. If I could fix this, then I could make the page taller when the modal is open and that may fix it.

Answer (score 0):

I've figured it out. I just needed to change the position from `fixed` to `absolute`.